# my pc with ubuntu 14.04 does not react for a really long time sometimes while playing videos on vlc media player?

Tags: vlc

When I play videos with VLC on Ubuntu 14.04, sometimes the screen stops at any random instant and does not move, but the audio keeps on playing until I switch the machine off. Any suggestions why am I facing this problem?